# Windows API Error 2 when installing MikTex (Win7)

Tags: miktex

I am trying to install MikTex 2.9.3927 on Windows 7 x64. Very early in the installation process, I get a MikTex setup wizard error saying: "Windows API Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified Details: C:...\somefile.tpm"

The file that results in the error seems to be different every time I try. I have tried many different installation paths, with many different setup options. The same error occurs if I download the ~138MB "Basic MiKTeX 2.9" Installer or if I use the Net Installer to download the entire setup (~1GB).

Note that this is a duplicate question - the other copy of this question is closed to users of under 10 rep.

I have asked it so that I can provide an updated answer...

Comment: Sigh.  Now I have to wait 8 hours to tell you the answer that I found!

Comment: I supplied it here if you're in a hurry... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26703/problem-installing-miktex-2-9-under-windows-xp-pro/78109#78109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is described in the MiKTeX Sourceforge bug ticket here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1935/

... set the MiKTeX installer to Compatibilty Mode Vista.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me in Win 10 x64 (it's many clicks to get to the Vista choice, but it changes nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Beside changing the name of the directory, I change the compatibility of the program (the miktex installation file) in windows 7, to work in the Windows XP mode. You have to right click on the icon and go to the compatibility tab.